# Use Moment.js to convert Unix epoch time to human readable time

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, epoch

I'm trying to use Moment.js to convert a Unix epoch time to a date and time. I'd also like to know how to have it formatted like below.

`Tuesday, November 22, 2016 6:00 PM`

Comment: did you read the docs?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can initialize a moment object with the unix timestamp and then use the [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) function to get your desired output.

```js
const yourUnixEpochTime = 1687340912000;
// Create moment object from epoch and convert to format:
const formattedTime = moment(yourUnixEpochTime).format("dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm A")

$("#time").text(formattedTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<p id="time"></p>
```

Comment: you can also break it with with HTML, which I think is pretty cool: `...format('dddd, <br> MMMM Do, YYYY  <br> h:mm:ss A')`

Answer (score 33):

From the Docs: [Unix Timestamp](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/)

```
var day = moment.unix(1318781876); //seconds
var day = moment(1318781876406); //milliseconds

// and then:

console.log(day.format('dddd MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));

// "Sunday October 16th 2011, 9:17:56 am"
```

Comment: NOTE: The above is backwards, `moment.unix(timestamp)` is for seconds and `moment(timstamp)` is for milliseconds. Not the other way round as the answer describes (at least in the latest version of moment).

Comment: @webnoob Thanks ! , changed it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.format('LLLL')` for your requirement.

```
let result = moment(epoch).format('LLLL');
```

```js
let epoch = 1562127342123;
let result = moment(epoch).format('LLLL');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`moment.unix(epochTime)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/).

Answer (score 0):

Moment JS converts the Unix time to GMT equivalent. To convert it to EST which is 5 hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) :
[momentjs]

```
const moment = require('moment');

console.log(moment(1580331903396).subtract(5, 'hours').format('MMMM Do, YYYY - h:mm:ss A '))
```

Refer working example here:

https://repl.it/repls/CumbersomeImmediateLibrary