# How to get timestamp format data from Firestore Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I save dates in a format like

[image: this]

in Cloud Firestore

How do I get it in Date format in Node.js?

Comment: What date format? I assume you can use moment. If yes, try `moment(value, 'DD MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss t').format(requiredDateFormat)`

Comment: Possibly in ms since epoch

Comment: Did you store the date using the Firebase sdk?

Comment: Yes, but also manually it has the same value

Comment: @NicholasSanti This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752287/use-moment-js-to-convert-unix-epoch-time-to-human-readable-time

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to cast what I get from firestore in a date format

Comment: Does [dateExample](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types) answer your question? They are using `admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date('December 10, 1815'))` to store a `Timestamp` in Firestore.

Comment: No, it doesn't I will directly save as MillisecondsSinceEpoch

Comment: Cool, then let's try using one of the constructors that are shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/dartlangexamples/api/dart-core/interfaces/comparable-hashable/date): `Date date = new Date.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int millisecondsSinceEpoch, [bool isUtc]);` to create a Date object from `MillisecondsSinceEpoch`. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Just realized after posting my comment that what I shared with you right above is Dartlang; nonetheless, the idea around it would be the same for Node.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get timestamps from Firestore they are of the following type:

[image]

To convert this into a Node.js timestamp you can use the .toDate() function.

For example, for a document like the following:

[image]

We can use something like:

```
db.collection('[COLLECTION]').doc('[DOCUMENT]').get().then(function(doc) {
  console.log(doc.data().[FIELD].toDate());
});
```

and the output will be like:

```
2019-12-16T16:27:33.031Z
```